# I have hots and neutrals where they don't belong

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm trying to run wire for light fixture I want to install in the ceiling. I seemingly had a light switch on the wall that went to nowhere. I opened it up and there is 1 14/2 wire running directly to the panel box and a 14/3 wire running somewhere I cannot find. It operates no lights, and no receptacles. The blacks are hot into the top of the switch, the red is also hot running into the bottom of the switch. The 2 whites are tied together, and are not hot. I thought I could tie all the hots (3 blacks and a red) and the 3 whites into neutral together but the breaker is tripping now. Any help is appreciated thanks[image]

Comment: What problem were you trying to fix? Is there a reason you couldn't leave it alone as it was?

Answer (score 4):

No kidding the breaker is tripping. You’ve created a dead short by connecting hot and neutral when the switch is in the “on” position.

Hot goes to one side of the switch, the load goes on the other side.